# Java Spring MVC integration test create OAuth2 Principal

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, principal, spring-oauth2

I've been trying to write an integration test for our Spring MVC application. We're using oAuth2 for authentication.

Spring in this case gives us a `Principal` instance which we use to determine which entities we have to send back to the client. In our controller we have an endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping("/bookings")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<List<ThirdPartyBooking>> getBookings(Principal principal) {
    OAuth2Authentication auth = (OAuth2Authentication) principal;
    OAuth2AuthenticationDetails authDetails = (OAuthAuthenticationDetails) auth.getDetails();
    // Extract stuff from the details...
}
```

Now in our test I want to make sure that we only send bookings for the authenticated user. Below the code for the test can be found:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {ThirdPartyBookingServiceConfiguration.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@Component
public abstract class RepositoryTestBase {
    @Resource
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldOnlyReturnUserBookings() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletResponse result = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/bookings").principal(???)).andReturn().getResponse();
        // Validate the response
    }
}
```

How would I insert a `OAuth2Authentication` at the `???`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use **RequestPostProcessor** for test authentication. Just add **stub token** to request:

```
@Component
public class OAuthHelper {

    @Autowired
    AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenservice;

    public RequestPostProcessor addBearerToken(final String username, String... authorities)
    {
        return mockRequest -> {
            OAuth2Request oauth2Request = new OAuth2Request( null, "client-id",
                        null, true, null, null, null, null, null );
            Authentication userauth = new TestingAuthenticationToken( username, null, authorities);
            OAuth2Authentication oauth2auth = new OAuth2Authentication(oauth2Request, userauth);
            OAuth2AccessToken token = tokenservice.createAccessToken(oauth2auth);

            mockRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.getValue());
            return mockRequest;
        };
    }
}
```

And use it in tests:

```
accessToken = authHelper.addBearerToken( TEST_USER, TEST_ROLE );
    mockMvc.perform( get( "/cats" ).with( accessToken ) )
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for. It did help greatly. Thanks!