# Could not autowire. No beans of 'AuthorizationServerTokenServices' type found. Spring OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want to test OAuth2 authorization and like in this answer:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326028/java-spring-mvc-integration-test-create-oauth2-principal](https://stackoverflow.com)

I'm trying to inject AuthorizationServerTokenServices into OAuthHelper:

```
@Component
public class OAuthHelper {


    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices;

    public RequestPostProcessor addBearerToken(final String username, String... authorities)
    {
        return mockRequest -> {
            OAuth2Request oauth2Request = new OAuth2Request( null, "client-id",
                    null, true, null, null, null, null, null );
            Authentication userauth = new TestingAuthenticationToken( username, null, authorities);
            OAuth2Authentication oauth2auth = new OAuth2Authentication(oauth2Request, userauth);
            OAuth2AccessToken token = tokenServices.createAccessToken(oauth2auth);
            mockRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.getValue());
            return mockRequest;
        };
    }
}
```

But ItelliJ doesn't find required bean:

'Could not autowire. No beans of 'AuthorizationServerTokenServices' type found.'

How can I fix it?

My pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!
    </parent>
    <artifactId>OwnerApp</artifactId>
    <version>${parent.version}</version>
    <name>OwnerApp</name>
    <description>OwnerApp</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>litvinov.al</groupId>
            <artifactId>Domain</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

I tried to change spring version, tried to instantiate DefaultTokenServices and TokenStore but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix it, now it works.

```
    @Component
    public class CustomAuthorizationServerTokenServices {
    
        @Bean
        public AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
            final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            defaultTokenServices.setAccessTokenValiditySeconds(-1);
            defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
            return defaultTokenServices;
        }
    
        private TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        }
    }
```